# Debugging a simple console game for Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in); 

System.out.println("Welcome to mini mad libs!"); // word1-word3 are inputs that point out which words from the story need to be replaced. 
System.out.printf("Please enter the story: ");
String story = keys.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Please enter the first word type that should be replaced:");
String word1 = keys.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Please enter the second word type that should be replaced:");
String word2 = keys.nextLine();
System.out.printf("Please enter the third word type that should be replaced:");
String word3 = keys.nextLine();
System.out.println();


System.out.println("Ok, the game is ready to play!"); //the replace strings are the new words that are replacing the original words in the story. 
System.out.println("Please enter a word type to replace "+word1);
String replace1 = keys.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter a word type to replace "+word2);
String replace2 = keys.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter a word to replace "+word3);
String replace3 = keys.nextLine();


String storyV2 = story.toLowerCase();
String word1V2 = word1.toLowerCase();
String word2V2 = word2.toLowerCase();
String word3V2 = word3.toLowerCase();


storyV2=storyV2.replaceAll("[.,!]", " "); 
int positionOf1= storyV2.indexOf(" "+word1V2+" ");
int positionOf2= storyV2.indexOf(" "+word2V2+" ");
int positionOf3= storyV2.indexOf(" "+word3V2+" "); 

int length1 = word1.length();
int length2 = word2.length();
int length3 = word3.length();

String WordMod1 = story.substring(positionOf1,positionOf1+length1);
String WordMod2 = story.substring(positionOf2,positionOf2+length2);
String WordMod3 = story.substring(positionOf3,positionOf3+length3); 

String lib = story.replaceFirst(WordMod1, replace1); //lib serves as a string that has a version of the original story replaced by the three words one by one in the next lines below. 
lib = lib.replaceFirst(WordMod2, replace2);
lib = lib.replaceFirst(WordMod3, replace3);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Here is your little mad lib: \n"+ lib); 
    }
}
```

Mad libz is a game that replaces selected words from a sentence with other words of your choice. I cannot use if/else statements, loops or anything that is not string methods. My problem seems to be in this part of the code. I'm not too experienced with Java so it might look terrible.

```
String WordMod1 = story.substring(positionOf1,positionOf1+length1);
String WordMod2 = story.substring(positionOf2,positionOf2+length2);
String WordMod3 = story.substring(positionOf3,positionOf3+length3);
```

This part is making a substrings that obtain the word in a sentence, for example if I want the word "noun", it looks the standalone word anywhere in the sentence instead of possible getting the word from other words like "pronoun" or "pronounced". PositionOf1 looks for the position between blank spaces and lenghtOf1 is the length of the original word we want to replace.

That is why this is also supposed to be case insensitive so that is why I made string storyV2, its a copy of the original set to lower case.

Comment: Did you get any error message? If so pls add the stack trace in an edit.

Comment: You wrote: _My problem seems to be in this part of the code_ Pardon me, but it is not clear to me what your problem is. Is your program not providing the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to replace one string with another, then why not using the replaceAll() method?

```
String story = "...";
String fromWord = "foo";
String toWord = "bar";
String newStory = story.replaceAll(" " + foo + " ", " " + bar + " ");
```

You could use more elaborate regex patterns for finding foo not only enclosed by spaces but all kinds of non-word characters, so you wouldn't need to remove characters like .,; etc. first as you currently do.